# Java EE Module Dependencies Eclipse

Tags: java, web-applications, classnotfoundexception, build-dependencies

I am developing a web application with Eclipse. I've set the build path to include my classes but sometimes I get the `ClassNotFoundException` and now I'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet MyServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.free.MyServlet
```

From the Servlet! *How is this possible*?

Comment: emphasis mine. Since seems like you're baffled. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using the integrated to Eclipse tomcat.
Most probably, your classes have not been copied under `WEB-INF\lib` of your web app in tomcat. Eclipse does that. Copy them mannually (from your project's `bin` directory). I am not sure how you keep it in sych with your coding project to avoid the mannual step